# Missing IPN Messages

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to handle Paypal IPN Messages being sent and processed by some Zapier zaps. But my issue has to do with the fact that I have a discrepancy between my downloaded transactions (from the Reports/Activity area) and the IPN history list.

I have 100's of IPN messages but they seem incomplete. I have a series of Tx ID's that appear in my activity download but do not have IPN entries corresponding to them. Is that possible?

Yes, they are all within the 28 day limit. I have 100's coming thru fine but then there are a bunch that are simply missing. Here are a list of various TX ID's that are missing from my IPN History:

```
1T067375AA633440U
8K138709R6731541F
3FP842931V7991231
93Y792144G594840E
0WN7539065955103H
20G90671C4171301X
3KK30383WF576573M
6XU56496HG8548825
6FX65228CG614502E
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a matter for Paypal support.

Comment: I suggest you to file a ticket to MTS since this is more to their technical issue.

Comment: Thank you both...

Comment: Yeh, an MTS ticket would be the correct path. https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/session/L3RpbWUvMTUxOTMyNDIzMS9nZW4vMTUxOTMyNDIzMS9zaWQvZlVZaEZWampJWGI3UiU3RVBHSkdKbGszJTdFbFlVdzhYYkVGa1V2aTZVT0lIaHFqSUd2dmpPN0JpSENIZGh1b0NMTiU3RTZvU1lGQ3VXT0liNGRNOW55VjdzenlaWGpDMDY2clAyUjM0azhyNUVySEwwbEpCX2lheXBVZnRnJTIxJTIx